# How can I create a time series line graph in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a python script that fetches data from an API to get weather temperature at a certain time

The result is a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Time,Temperature
2020-02-15 18:37:39,-8.25
2020-02-15 19:07:39,-8.08
2020-02-15 19:37:39,-8.41
2020-02-15 20:07:39,-8.2
```

How can transform the CSV into a JavaScript array and make a Chart.js line chart out of it?

Right now, I have a Chart.js base script that looks like this (isn't filled with any data)

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
type: 'line',
 data: {
   labels: [],
   datasets: [{ 
       data: [],
       label: "Temperature",
       borderColor: "#3e95cd",
       fill: false
     } 
   ]
 },
 options: {
   scales: {
     xAxes: [{
       type: 'time',
       distribution: 'linear',
     }],
   title: {
     display: false,
   }
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: Step 1 is usually "use some kind of CSV reader". What have you tried?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, **convert** every single file-line **string**:

```
2020-02-15 18:37:39,-8.25
```

into an **Object**:

```
{x: "2020-02-15 18:37:39", y: -8.25}
```

to be stored inside the Chart.js `data : []` Array.

Here's an example on how to create a function `csvToChartData()` that returns such an Array (to be used like: ... `data: csvToChartData(csv)` )

- **Trim and split** a file string by **newline** `\n` into a `lines` array .
- **Remove titles** (the first array key) by using `lines.shift();`
- Convert every **line to an object** `{x: date, y: temperature}` by splitting each line by comma `.split(',')`
- Pass that newly mapped Array (by using `.map()`) as your chart **`data:`**

```js
const csv = `Time,Temperature
2020-02-15 18:37:39,-8.25
2020-02-15 19:07:39,-8.08
2020-02-15 19:37:39,-8.41
2020-02-15 20:07:39,-8.2`;

const csvToChartData = csv => {
  const lines = csv.trim().split('\n');
  lines.shift(); // remove titles (first line)
  return lines.map(line => {
    const [date, temperature] = line.split(',');
    return {
      x: date,
      y: temperature
    }
  });
};

const ctx = document.querySelector("#line-chart").getContext('2d');
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: csvToChartData(csv),
      label: "Temperature",
      borderColor: "#3e95cd",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        distribution: 'linear',
      }],
      title: {
        display: false,
      }
    }
  }
};
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
#line-chart {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

## Fetch data dynamically:

[image]

To fetch the data dynamically, say **every 5 seconds**, you could use AJAX and the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
Here's the modified JS example given you have a CSV file called `temperature.csv`

```js
const config = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [], // Set initially to empty data
      label: "Temperature",
      borderColor: "#3e95cd",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        distribution: "linear"
      }],
      title: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.querySelector("#line-chart").getContext("2d");
const temperatureChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

const csvToChartData = csv => {
  const lines = csv.trim().split("\n");
  lines.shift(); // remove titles (first line)
  return lines.map(line => {
    const [date, temperature] = line.split(",");
    return {
      x: date,
      y: temperature
    };
  });
};

const fetchCSV = () => fetch("temperature.csv")
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then(csv => {
    temperatureChart.data.datasets[0].data = csvToChartData(csv);
    temperatureChart.update();
    setTimeout(fetchCSV, 5000); // Repeat every 5 sec
  });

fetchCSV(); // First fetch!
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm!

And I guess I could set the _const csv_ value to a csv reader to make it update automatically?

Comment: `const csv = ` should point to the CSV string, yes. For automatic/dynamic updates you should consider the Chart.js documentation https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Do you happen to know how I could make my chart update automatically when I edit the CSV (let's say the API writes a new line to the file) ? Maybe set the `const csv` as the string content of the CSV?

Comment: @Power_Lemming you can use WebSockets, to keep an active channel of *"polling"* connection (via really small packets) to the server. Done that, create a backend logic (Node.js) that will, after the file changes, notify the listening channels with the new CVS data. The other simpler way is to (say every minute or 30 sec) ping the server using AJAX and simply contact a backend script, which, if the CSV file's **modified-date** changed will return the fresh data (or `0` or `null` if there was no change).

Comment: @Power_Lemming added a slightly modified code that uses the Fetch API to get the `temperature.csv` data every 5 seconds.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I tried to import the CSV as an array and then transform is into a string, without success. Your little code modification works perfectly!

Comment: This is great solution Rocko, though we could also use d3 csv parser to parse csv data. I was wondering if it is also possible to aggregate values from csv like show data for last 30 minutes or previous day , something like that ?

Comment: @Novice I don't think it should be hard to `.filter()` the `lines` Array by some "time" condition. After the filtering is done, simply return that filtered (instead of the entire) array.

Comment: Thanks Rocko, not really that good I am with chart.js, I mostly use plotly, hence asked. though do not want to waste your time, but just curious if you could direct me to something like that where it has been done or reference of some working example, please ignore if that is too much of ask :)

Comment: @Novice I'm not going to do an example, hence "30min ago" or "previous day" might not be the 30 min / day / for a future visitor. Anyways, having a data with a dateTime, you should get the User current time (here I suggest to use a library like Moment.js or https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-format), compare the user time and the data time, filter the array (as I said) and send that filtered array to (really) any chart plugin you're most familiar with.

Comment: Thanks Roko, I did it now in plotly, thanks for all the valuable information though.:)

Comment: Works perfectly! I've to add that it I had to change the Date Format because it was messing around with it. (European style). I don't know if there's any setting available to set the date format (for avoiding errors because of defaults). Thanks

Comment: @EncryptEx yes, there's the ISO standard that's used by JS's [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).  Read more about it here: [ISO 8601 (*Wikipedia*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Syntax: `2020-02-15 18:37:39`