# Unable to display data via Charts.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js, frontend

I am using Charts.JS for the first time, and I am coming across an issue where I cannot display the data.

Simply put, I am returning the data from an API, but unable to display it. I might be doing something wrong, but I figured I'd ask in case anyone has a suggestion.

Also, I tried scouring StackOverflow before posting this. I could not find a relevant post. If you know one, please share it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
function renderChart(data) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("vitalSignsCanvas").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'This week',
        data: data[0],
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          }
        }]
      },
    }
  });
}

function getVitalSign(memberIDNum, shiftFromDate, shiftToDate, isLive, baseURL) {
  var webMethod = baseURL + "/api/GetVitalSign";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: webMethod,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      memberID: memberIDNum,
      fromDate: shiftFromDate,
      toDate: shiftToDate
    },
    success: function(result) {
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(result);

      var data = [];
      data.push(parsedData.Answer);
      renderChart(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
      alert("An error occurred. Please contact the Support Team.");
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(xhr.status);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Vital Signs for <span class="memberName"></span></h3>
          <br>
          <canvas id="vitalSignsCanvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer-vitalSigns">
          <p>Application &copy; 2020</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

PS: the data being an Array of objects i.e:  `[{"Question":"Temperature", "QuestionID":30060, "Answer":87.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-27T10:59:34.27", "PAHID":5}, ...... ]`

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the Data that gets returned? P.S: `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));`

Comment: Since the data is already JSON, are you sure you need the `JSON.parse` ? If this `console.log(typeof result)` gives you `Object` (instead of `String`) than there's no need to parse an Object

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan [{\"Question\":\"Temperature\",\"QuestionID\":30060,\"Answer\":87.00,\"SavedDate\":\"2020-02-27T10:59:34.27\",\"PAHID\":5},

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I figured I'd parse the data since I wasn't able to print it.

Comment: is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244909/383904

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan trying to makr it work, but no luck.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208868/discussion-between-alex-greenwood-and-roko-c-buljan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you return a `response` as **`Object`** (test using `console.log(typeof response)`)
- Make sure to convert your data into the expected format (see the
  `dataToChartData` function that accepts an Array of objects).
- Inside your success handler simply call this two lines:

```
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = dataToChartData(result);
    myChart.update();
```

**Example:**

```js
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'This week',
      data: [], // Set initially to empty data
      borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html
        type: "time",
        distribution: "linear",
        time: {
          // parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', // Not needed
          unit: 'custom',
          displayFormats: {
            'custom': 'YYYY-MM-DD', // or like: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          source: 'data'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }],
      /*title: {
        display: false
      }*/
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.querySelector("#vitalSignsCanvas").getContext("2d");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

const dataToChartData = arr => {
  return arr.map(item => {
    return {
      x: item.SavedDate,
      y: item.Answer
    };
  });
};

// Sample result for demo:
const result = [{
    "Question": "Temperature", "QuestionID": 30060, "Answer": 87.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-14T10:59:34.27Z", "PAHID": 1
  },{
    "Question": "Temperature", "QuestionID": 30060, "Answer": 92.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-15T10:59:34.45Z", "PAHID": 2
  },{
    "Question": "Temperature", "QuestionID": 30060, "Answer": 64.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-16T10:59:34.45Z", "PAHID": 3
  },{
    "Question": "Temperature", "QuestionID": 30060, "Answer": 67.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-17T10:59:34.45Z", "PAHID": 4
  },{
    "Question": "Temperature", "QuestionID": 30060, "Answer": 98.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-18T10:59:34.45Z", "PAHID": 5
  },{
    "Question": "Temperature", "QuestionID": 30060, "Answer": 77.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-19T10:59:34.45Z", "PAHID": 6
  },{
    "Question": "Temperature", "QuestionID": 30060, "Answer": 81.00, "SavedDate": "2020-02-20T10:59:34.45Z", "PAHID": 7
  }
];

// This goes inside the Success handler
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = dataToChartData(result);
myChart.update();
```

```css
#vitalSignsCanvas {display: block; width: 100%; min-height: 200px;}
```

```html
<h3>Vital Signs for: <span class="memberName">Chart</span></h3>
<canvas id="vitalSignsCanvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

Code inspiration from [my other answer (How to create a time series line graph in Chart js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244808/how-can-i-create-a-time-series-line-graph-in-chart-js)