# React-chartjs-2 line chart with x and y data not working

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I've been trying to figure out how to create a line chart that plots data in this
format {x:time,y:data}.

Basically exactly like this post.

[How can I create a time series line graph in chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244808/how-can-i-create-a-time-series-line-graph-in-chart-js)

Problem is it that i can't manage to get it to work using the react-chartjs2 library.

Below is my code and a link to a image of my graph.

```
class Grafer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'time-data',
        data: [
          { x: '2021-08-21 18:37:39', y: 2 },
          { x: '2021-08-22 18:39:39', y: 3 },
          { x: '2021-09-25 18:44:39', y: 1 },
        ],
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.8)',
        tension: 0.3,
      },
    ],
  };

  options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart',
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            type: 'time',
            distribution: 'linear',
          },
        ],
        title: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Line data={this.data} options={this.options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Grafer;
```

[image to see my line-graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTppg.png)